# when create note in evernote in evernote api, raise Evernote::EDAM::Error::EDAMUserException

Tags: ruby, api, evernote

here is my [full code](https://gist.github.com/9636aa4770f67e7729d7), following is my code:

```
note_store = c.note_store
note_title = ::Time.now.to_s
note_body = ::Time.now.to_s
n_body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
n_body += "<!DOCTYPE en-n SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
n_body += "<en-n>#{note_body}</en-n>"

## Create n object
our_note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new
our_note.title = note_title
our_note.content = n_body
```

I'm sure my developer token can work for search evernote notes, but when i create note, it raise this error

the full error is:

```
<Evernote::EDAM::Error::EDAMUserException errorCode:ENML_VALIDATION (11), parameter:"Element type \"en-n\" must be declared.">
```

Answer (score 1):

see [here](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/creating_notes.php), following code will work

```
note_store = c.note_store
note_title = ::Time.now.to_s
note_body = <<-CONTENT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">
<en-note>#{::Time.now}</en-note>
CONTENT

## Create n object
our_note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new
our_note.title = note_title
our_note.content = note_body;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to clear all files in c:\users\%username%\appdata\local\evernote or the equivalent in your OS environment.